# Foxit PhantomPDF: Snapshot to PDF

Tags: pdf, export, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

To my knowledge, the best method to
extract a `.pdf` image from a `.pdf` report
in `Foxit PhantomPDF` is to:

1. Duplicate the page on which the image exists.
2. Crop the page down.
3. Save the page as a new `.pdf`.

Is there definitely no `Snapshot to PDF` or `Export Selection to PDF` tool?

The method mentioned isn't too time intensive,
but I want to be sure I'm not using an unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Snapshot tool in Foxit PhantomPDF and Foxit Reader on the Home tab which lets you copy a rectangular area to the clipboard. Once you have done that go to "File > Create > From Clipboard" to create a PDF from the snapshot you have taken.

Comment: Doesn't snapshot to clipboard grab a scalar image though? I would assume that this is lossy, as the create PDF would be created from a scalar image.